# Azure Boards - How to find over booked team member in sprint

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-boards

We've recently started using Azure Boards and Sprints. Say we have two Team members, each with 20 hours a week capacity, 2 week sprint. Total team sprint capacity is then 80 hours. Now lets say I have 80 hours of tasks, 60 are assigned to team member A, 20 to team member B. Accident of course, but where in Azure Boards can we discover this aside from adding up each task effort remaining?

The sprint seems very team based, looking for some audit tools to balance the workload properly. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is captured on the sprint page when you filter to show Work Details.  You can reference the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/adjust-work?view=azure-devops) to see it in action.  This is driven off the "Remaining Work" field, so you will have to populate and keep it updated during the sprint to see it updating daily in real-time.

> [image]