# How to NOT use story point in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I totally understand what are story points and their advantage and inconvenient, but I'm trying to motivate the team to move to Azure DevOps, and currently we do not use story point(but rather estimations done by the whole team). I know it's not ideal, but it's not the point.

I would like to know if it's possible to configure Azure Devops to not work with Story points but with effort?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you would want to use the "Scrum" template instead of the "Agile" template for your project.  "Scrum" template has "Product Backlog Items" instead of "Stories".  It also uses Effort instead of Story Points.  Is there a reason you might be stuck on the "Agile" template?

Comment: I was finding nomenclature clearer, but no, no specific reason, I had to choose one.

Answer (score 3):

Just as *Matt* pointed out in the comment, you could choose to **use Scrum workflow** instead of Agile workflow

Effort is for Product Backlog Items (in Scrum template) and Story Points is for User Stories (in Agile template).

[image: Portfolio Backlog Workflow]

> **Effort**
>
> Estimate the amount of work required to complete a PBI using any unit
> of measurement your team prefers, such as story points or time. A
> numeric value is required.

Once a Scrum team have completed the product backlog item estimates they then go on to break each PBI down in to tasks. They then do time-based estimates on the tasks (e.g. Task 1 = 2 hours).

More detail info and process you could refer our official doc--[Scrum process work item types and workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?view=azure-devops)

---

**Update:**

It's controlled by working days and Capacity per day, you could simply refer below sample screenshot.

[image: Working Days]

[image: Sprint Planned Effort]

Comment: Okay, once tasks are implemented, how to fill an iteration with just enough work according to the team capacity?

Comment: That's probably a separate question, but this answer probably mostly covers what you are looking for:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304611/azure-boards-how-to-find-over-booked-team-member-in-sprint/63306584#63306584

Comment: @J4N Agreed with Matt. Use [capacity bars](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/adjust-work?view=azure-devops) to make these determinations:1. Adjust your sprint plan if your team is over or under capacity
2.Load balance work across your team 3.Quickly reassign tasks to another team member Besides, you could also take a look at other's suggestion and experience here:[What should we do if there are not enough PBIs to fill a final Sprint in Scrum?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/what-should-we-do-if-there-are-not-enough-pbis-to-fill-a-final-sprint-in-scrum)

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT On what is based those capacity bars? I've made a small test with only me available a few hours/week, but even if I add tasks that have "effort" specified, the bars remains at 0/9h.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT You can't just estimate a product backlog item? I see that it takes in account the estimate of sub task, but often we have product backlog items that are small enough. Also how to add  job to the sprint while seing the utilization of the sprint?

Comment: @J4N For question 1, please refer my updated screenshot. For question 2, we could directly use the **effort field** for estimations in parent items (such as stories, PBI's or bugs). The effort can be a unit like story points, complexity points, or - even hours. So, the engineer first estimates the whole story, then breaks it down into tasks, and *tracks time on the tasks.*

Comment: If you proceed like this, you can use the some 3rd-party tool such as *Timetracker* pace field that indicates the ratio between initially-estimated effort and the eventual tracked time. As estimation skills are usually some kind of holy grail, this is very educational for the team to understand previous estimations after work has been finished. (Start here for additional information: [Iterations Page Overview](https://support.7pace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000581603--Iterations-Page-Overview)))

Comment: how to make this view take in account the effort field of the PBI into the usage ?

Comment: @J4N Not sure if totally get your point. You could check the level of effort displayed in the sprint window. As you assign backlog items to a sprint, the sprint window updates with a running **tally of the number of backlog items and tasks, as well as the Planned Effort.** Planned Effort provides a sum of all  Effort defined for backlog items assigned to the sprint. This represents your **initial guess** at what your team will be able to complete in the sprint. Next, you'll define tasks, estimate that work, and use *your team's capacity* to make sure it fits in the sprint.

Comment: More details kindly refer our doc here-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops#assign-work-from-your-backlog-to-a-sprint  Hope it is clearly.

Comment: Hi @J4N, Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer* which will also help others in the community.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Not really, with the team we estimate a bunch of tasks, then we try to fit what we can in our sprint. We rarely create tasks.